# How to send the Claims with token in web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, jwt

I have a WebApi in .NET Core with token authorization.
I followed a guide to implement it, but the response only shows the token, and it's ok, but I would like to see other claims.

This is my code:

```
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]Personal personal)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var userId = GetUserIdFromCredentials(personal);
                if (!userId.HasValue)
                {
                    return Unauthorized();
                }
                var rolUsuario = _context.Personales.Include(p => p.RolPersonal).Select(x => x.RolPersonal.Descripcion).FirstOrDefault();

                var claims = new[]
                {
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, rolUsuario),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, personal.CorreoE),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                };

                var token = new JwtSecurityToken
                (
                    issuer: _configuration["Issuer"],
                    audience: _configuration["Audience"],
                    claims: claims,
                    expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(5),
                    notBefore: DateTime.UtcNow,
                    signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["SigningKey"])),
                         SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
                );
                //var token_email = token.Claims.Where(w => w.Type == "email").Select(s => s.Value).FirstOrDefault();
                //HttpContext.Session.SetString("token_email", token_email);
                return Ok(new{ token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token) });
            }

            return BadRequest();
        }
```

The result looks like this:

```
{ 
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJ....oTT7KI6kcZy-o" 
}
```

I would like to see the email claims for example:

```
{ 
    "email": bla@bla.com,
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJ....oTT7KI6kcZy-o" 
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I understand what you are asking for, and jps has the answer for that. However, what you are doing probably is redundant. Because the token itself contains the claim already. The application (probably a server side app) that is accepting and validating the token can read the email and any other value from that token. You may go to jwt.io and paste your token to see the email value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply extend the anonymous object that you're already using like this:

```
return Ok(new { email = personal.CorreoE, token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token)});
```

The result will look like:

```
{"email":"email@exmaple.com","token":"eyJ....."}
```

Beside that, you can of course also decode the token on client side and extract all the claims that you added on server side.
Check https://jwt.io to see the contents of your token.

Comment: But that's not a JWT Token anymore, just a regular json result.

Comment: @Tseng You get a JSON result that contains the email address and the JWT. In the original example posted in the question you get a JSON result that only contains the token. Where do you see a problem? It's the normal way, that you receive a JSON containing the token and sometimes other information as well, e.g. a refresh token